# RecyclerView's OnItemClick triggering before its child's OnClick

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, imageview, onclicklistener

I am having some problems in my school project. My RecyclerView's `OnItemClick` is being triggered when I click on an ImageButton that is inside of it.

`CODE`

```
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, mRecyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
    viewComments(posts.get(position));
  }

  @Override
  public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {

  }
}));
```

And here's the RecyclerItemClickListener code:

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

  private OnItemClickListener mListener;
  private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

  public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);

    void onItemLongClick(View view, int position);
  }

  public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;

    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        View childView = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

        if (childView.findViewById(R.id.btnRateUp).isPressed() || childView.findViewById(R.id.btnRateDown).isPressed()) {
          return false;
        }

        return true;
      }

      @Override
      public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        View childView = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

        if (childView != null && mListener != null) {
          mListener.onItemLongClick(childView, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
    View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

    if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
      mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
    }

    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
  }
}
```

This is what I came up with to detect if the child was getting the click,

```
if(childView.findViewById(R.id.btnRateUp).isPressed() || childView.findViewById(R.id.btnRateDown).isPressed())
```

but I have realized the method `isPressed()` takes longer than the RecyclerView's `OnItemClick` to process. The code only works when I don't tap on it quickly.

btnRateUp and btnRateDown are ImageButtons and their `OnClick` events are being implemented in the Adapter's `onBindViewHolder` as follows:

```
holder.getBtnRateUp().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    doStuff(true);
  }
});

holder.getBtnRateDown().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    doStuff(false);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the way I was doing it completely. Followed [this](https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/) tutorial.